Blender Newbie Import GLTF Issues
I am having issues importing models and animations into Blender. I need to combine models and animations I have into one file. I am exporting models from Unreal to use in a different engine that requires the animations to all be in the same file to work.
I prefer to use gltf as its text based and easier on source control.
Here is a screenshot of the model in Unreal.

Screenshot of one of the animations in Unreal.

The export settings in Unreal.

Blender import settings

The model imported into Blender.


I did some research and I should be able to fix it by deleting gltf_Not_Exported but this is what the model looks like after deleting it.

I tried doing the same process with FBX and ran into similar issues where the model imported fine but the animations were wrong like here. I'm using Blender 4.3.0. How can I fix this?

I got it figured out. I looked around and found this on the Unreal export settings. The second one stood out as the most likely culprit and disabling it, the model now imports correctly.

Export Vertex Colors: While Blender can handle vertex colors, it's important to ensure that they're used correctly in Unreal Engine and that the color format is compatible.
Export Vertex Skin Weights: If your mesh has complex skinning, Blender might struggle with it.
Use Mesh Quantization: Quantization can reduce file size, but it can also lead to loss of precision in vertex positions and normals.


Although I spoke to soon as Unreal wont allow exporting animations with Export Vertex Skin Weights disabled. So I have to find a way to get this working so I can use it in a different engine. I was informed that there is a Bones option in Viewport Overlays and disabling this fixes the problem but causes the animations to not work.
